# Como criar relatórios no Cristal Report com dados de 2 ou mais tabelas?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

Como eu crio relatórios pelo Cristal Reports, utilizando um DataSet que contenha mais de uma Tabela? Com uma tabela eu consigo trabalhar normal, porém quando eu insiro mais de uma tabela o resultado do Relatório vem em branco. A unica coisa que fiz após a conexão foi selecionar os Data Field's e colar no relatório.

Segue imagens:

[image: O DataSet utilizado no relatório]

[image: Aqui é o próprio relatório]

Segue também a minha chamativa do relatório pelo MVC:

```
    public ActionResult relatorio_pdf()
    {
        connectionRateio.ConectarBanco(modelLoginRateio);

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        var query = @"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE MT INNER JOIN MYOTHERTABLE MOT ON MT.ID = MOT.ID";

        var command = new OracleCommand(query, connectionRateio.connection);


        var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();

        rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Relatorios/relatorio.rpt");
        rptH.Load();
        rptH.SetDataSource(dataTable);

        Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

        connectionRateio.FecharConexaoBanco();

        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Não custa perguntar: Se você fizer um **SELECT * FROM MYTABLE MT INNER JOIN MYOTHERTABLE MOT ON MT.ID = MOT.ID** no banco de dados ele retorna os resultados?

Comment: Rs... Sim, sim. A query está certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar o problema e uma solução!

O **Database Field** configurado acima é um **Database Field** do tipo XML, no qual tem total compatibilidade a consultas com uma tabela. Porém ao consultar 2 ou mais ele não retorna nada, e isso não sei o porque. Para solucionar o problema eu criei um novo tipo de **Database Field** do tipo Oracle Server, coloquei as tabelas que eu precisava e adicionei uma linha no código para efetuar o logon no momento da chamativa do relatório, segue a linha:

```
public ActionResult relatorio_pdf()
{
    ...
    rptH.SetDatabaseLogon("usuario.banco","senha123");// <-Esta linha..
    ...
}
```

Fazendo isso o meu relatório consegue entender os **join's** feitos na chamativa dele sem nenhum problema.

Answer (score 1):

Algo interessante seria colocar em seu projeto um DataSet e adicionar a ele as tabelas com as quais você irá trabalhar, estando estas acompanhadas de um TableAdapter adicional que seja construído a partir de sua consulta

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE MT INNER JOIN MYOTHERTABLE MOT ON MT.ID = MOT.ID
```

Então, no momento da criação do relatório, bastaria selecionar essa única tabela presente na conexão usada pelo DataSet e os *Database Fields* desejados.

Este [artigo](http://www.macoratti.net/13/01/c_crpt1.htm), embora não esteja fazendo isso exatamente, pode ajudá-lo a entender melhor alguns pormenores do processo de criação básico de um relatório com associação de múltiplas tabelas.

Comment: Ainda estou tentando solucionar o problema mas não consigo. Já refiz uma 5 vezes, criei um novo e acontece a mesma coisa. Ele retorna valores nulos quando apresento duas tabelas de um DataField.